# Hibernate - get the wrong entities from my example tables. It looks like table columns are "exchanged"

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, join

I have in my sql server 2016 database three tables as example for an Hibernate application which uses a join table with an additional column to assign articles buyed from an customer with a specific amount. My tables in the DB are:

**table_article** `(a_id int, description varchar(255))`

```
a_id   description  
1      fish         
2      fish         
3      water
```

**table_customer** `(customer_id int, name varchar(255)`

```
customer_id   name  
1      john         
2      jane         
3      jack
```

**ac_join_table** `(a_id, customer_id, amount, pk(a_id, customer_id))`

```
a_id   customer_id amount  
1      2           10   
2      1           3        
2      3           7   
2      2           18        
3      1           5
```

So customer jane with id 2 buys 10 fishes. **If I run my programm it looks like the table columns from the join table were interpreted different or exchanged.** Because if I run the following code jane buys 3 fishes, 18 fishes and 7 fishes. It looks like the article_id is interpreted as customer_id if I run:

```
// should return that jane (customer_id: 2) buys 10 fishes (a_id: 1, amount: 10)
// but it interprets a_id as customer_id so jane buys 3, 7 and 18 fishes...

Cust c = sessionObj.get(Cust.class, 2); 
List<ArtCustJoin> articles = c.getArtikel();
for (ArtCustJoin artCustJoin : articles) {
     System.out.println(artCustJoin.getArt().getDescription());
}
```

My Java classes for the Hibernate model are:

**Art.java for table_article**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_article")
public class Art {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private int article_id;

    @Column
    private String description;
     // …
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ku")
    private List<ArtCustJoin> customers;     
    // …    
    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

**Cust.java for table_customer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_customer")
public class Cust {
    @Id
    private int customer_id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="art")
    private List<ArtCustJoin> artikel;

    // getter + setter
    // ...
}
```

**ArtCustJoin.java for the join table ac_join_table. The join table has an additional column amount**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo", name="ac_join_table")
public class ArtCustJoin {

    // Use Compound Key instead of single primitive key
    @EmbeddedId
    CompositeKey id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id", columnDefinition="int", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ARTID"))
    @MapsId("article_id") // maps to attribute with this name in class Artikel
    private Art art;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CUSTID"))
    @MapsId("customer_id") // maps to attribute with this name in class Kunde
    private Cust ku;


    @Column
    private int amount;


    public CompositeKey getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(CompositeKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getter + setter
    // ...
}
```

**And a class for the composite key:**

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable{
    @Column
    private Integer a_id;

    @Column
    private Integer customer_id;

    public CompositeKey() {}
    // ...
}
```

I dont know where the error is that column a_id is interpreted as customer_id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no java developer but both `@OneToMany(mappedBy=` seem weird and look like the reason of the issue. Isn't `Customer` supposed to be mapped to `ArtCustJoin` by `customer_id`? instead of `@OneToMany(mappedBy="art")`. The same applies to `Art` class.